# Mapping Java Generic to String value

Tags: hibernate, generics, java-8

I want to persist into DB 2 entities :

- Attribute

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Attribute<T> {

  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  Long id;

  @ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
  Item item;

  String name;

  T value;

  boolean isTemplate;
  // skip setter and getter
  }
  ```
- Item

  ```
  public class Item {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  Long id;

  @OneToMany(cascade = ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name= "item_id")
  List<Attribute> attributes;

  private boolean isTemplate;
      // skip setter and getter
  }

  in short Item 1-->* Attribute
  ```
- Error message that i get because hibernate can't map T value;

  > Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'sessionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Property domain.item.Attribute.value has an unbound type and no explicit target entity. Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=) or use an explicit @Type
- I only need this simple table

  - Item
    | id:int | isTemplate:boolean |
  - Attribute
    | id:int | Name:String | type:String (i.e:String,Integer - > based value type) | value:String | fk_item_id |

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't persist generic T due to java type erasure [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). Type T exist only in source and at  runtime it's type Object. hibernate doent's know how to store / present Object in database it might be any type - entity , collection ,embeded object , some simple object - string , integer .....

Also in relational databases you can't persist java object without appropriate type (you can try to serialize object and  save it as blob and in java side de-serialize it :) :) )

General :

1. if T it's entity : need to provide an interface/superclass instead of T, be it only an empty marker one if the differences between subclasses are large.

   @ManyToOne(targetEntity=T_EntityClass.class)
   @JoinColumn(name = "")
   private T value;
2. if it's not entity - looks like your case : 
   create abstract entity with all fields except value field , and extends from this entity child - implementation , like for String , Integer....

   ```
   @Entity
   @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
   public abstract class Attribute<T> {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;

       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
       private Item item;

       @Column
       private String name;

       @Column
       boolean isTemplate;

       public abstract T getValue();

       public abstract void setValue(T value);
       ........
      }
   ```

String implementation :

```
@Entity
public class AttributeStringValue extends Attribute<String>{

    @Column
    String value;

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Integer implementation :

```
@Entity
public class AttributeIntegerValue extends Attribute<Integer>{

    @Column
    Integer value;

    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

as result you have 3 tables :

```
create table attribute (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    is_template boolean,
    name varchar(255),
    item_id bigint,
    primary key (id)
)

create table attribute_integer_value (
    value integer,
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)

create table attribute_string_value (
    value varchar(255),
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

sbjavateam, thank you for your thoroughly explanation. I have arrived in almost the same conclusion after I try to implement `AttributeConverter`. I stuck to convert `T value` to to String. It ends up to use `instance of` to get Object type only but I cant map its value. It is well explained in your explained `Also in relational databases you can't persist java object without appropriate type`.

I ends up almost the same approach like you to create additional class wrapper but `Attribute<T>` really a good idea.... It brings me arsenal to prove `design your entity first clean and nice and do mapping latter`.